1980s (or 90s) story from "Asimov's" - man is cursed with success at Bingo
I have a vague memory of a man who goes to bingo games (possibly at a trailer park); he talks to someone who has been winning all night in the parking lot after the night is always, and somehow is given the curse of winning; it's a curse because it's associated with him becoming estranged from everyone else at the games, to the point that he almost loses the ability to speak (I have a vague memory that he can't or chooses not to, call out "BINGO" when he wins, or maybe that's the person he got the curse from), but he keeps winning.

"Mrs. Shummel Exits a Winner" by John Kessel, Asimov's June 1988.
A boy who can't speak isn't even trying to win with his single card:

Schuster called five numbers. The boy had four of them, a clear winning diagonal that shot across the board like an arrow into Martha's heart. He remained mute as a snake, and somebody else won two numbers later. He had both of those numbers, too.
She sat there and, with an anxiety that grew like a tumor, watched him win the next five games in a row, none of which he called out. The room faded into the background until all there was was the boy's bingo board. Schuster would call a number, and it was as if he were reading them off the kid's battered pasteboard. Still the boy said nothing. He let other people take $150 that could have been his.

The card that always wins comes with a curse of losing the ability to speak:

YOU WILL GIVE UP YOUR VOICE.
Martha felt flushed. She could see everything so clearly it almost hurt. Her senses seemed as sharp as if she were twenty again; her eyes picked out every hair on the boy’s arm, she smelled the aroma of food from the hall and garbage from the alley. Across the city somewhere a truck was climbing up the gears away from a stoplight.
"You're kidding."
NO.
"How will you take my voice?"
I DON'T TAKE—YOU GIVE.
"How can I give you my voice?"
SAY YES.
What did she have to lose? There was no way he could steal a person's voice. Besides, you had to take a chance in your life. "All right," she said.
The boy nodded. "Good-bye," he said: softly, almost a whisper.


Thank you.  I might have found that if I hadn't been sure the protagonist was male!
